# Apple Maps link not opening native app through Chrome for iOS

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've built a custom Google map that includes a function that either sets a link to open in Apple Maps or Google Maps:

```
function mapsSelector(lat, long) {
  /* If on iOS, open in Apple Maps */
  if ((navigator.platform.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.platform.indexOf('iPad') != -1)) {
    window.open('http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=' + lat + ',' + long + '&dirflg=w');
  /* else, use Google */
  } else {
    window.open('https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=' + lat + ',' + long + '&travelmode=bicycling');
  }
}
```

It works on my website when it's run as a web app or in Safari (it opens Apple Maps), but in Chrome for iOS, it briefly opens a new tab, which then immediately closes. If the same URL is opened as a standard `href`, it works as expected, so I imagine it's something to do with the way the function triggers the link.

To reproduce, you can go to http://nyceboarding.com/map.html, tap on any marker, and then the "Get Directions" link.

Answer (score 0):

They key is iOS users use a different protocol at the beginning. Try changing the "http://" in the iOS block to "maps://" and see if that works.

Comment: Your else block is fine, Google and Android users will be able to use that.

Comment: I tried with maps:// before using http://. I switched because [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) use http:// instead of maps://. As I mentioned, the current link works fine in Safari, just not Chrome on iOS

Comment: Yes. Looks like it's a security issue in Chrome for iOS. I re-worked the function and set the variable URL as a `href` without `target="_blank"`, which works

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
www.google.com/maps/...
```

to

```
maps.google.com/maps/...
```